# removeLocationUpdates()/requestLocationUpdates() or disconnect()/requestLocationUpdates()

Tags: android, location, locationlistener

let's say I have a `GoogleApiClient` instance and 2 `LocationListener`s:

```
GoogleApiClient gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
  .addApi( LocationServices.API )
  .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
  .build();

LocationListener listenerA, listenerB;

LocationRequest requestA, requestB;

initTheAboveInstances();

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( gac, requestA, listenerA );
```

At some point later, I want to replace `listenerA` with `listenerB`. What's the best (recommended) way to accomplish that?

By

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates( gac, listenerA );
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( gac, requestB, listenerB );
```

or by:

```
gac.disconnect();
gac.connect();
```

and request the updates in `onConnected()` method

```
@Override
public void onConnected( Bundle state ) {
  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( gac, requestB, listenerB );
}
```

?

my problem is, that in some cases the `listenerB.onLocationChanged()` is not get called...

TIA

Comment: which way did you use? remove and request, or requesting location updates in onconnected after disconnecting googleapiclient?

Comment: I stayed with remove/request-locationUdates

Comment: thanks will do the same.